# How can we disable monitoring temporarily for a variable node in milo?

Tags: milo

I am using digitalpetri opcua client sdk (now milo).

I would like to temporarily disable a few of monitored items which are part of my subscription in OPCUA client. How can I do that? There seems to be a way to set *MonitoringMode* to disabled. Is that the correct way?

I don't want to disconnect my client and I would like to renew the subscription for the monitored item at some future time.

Answer (score 0):

After some more research I found my answer. It looks like this setting can be used to enable/disable the sampling and reporting. check http://documentation.unified-automation.com/uasdkc/1.4.0/html/L2UaSubscription.html